# Excel formula to return number of numerical instances (that are separated by spaces) from varying text string

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a Microsoft Excel problem where there's a column with hugely varying numbers of alphanumerical characters in each cell. Each cell contains both full sentences, and most contain lists of uniquely identifiable components.
Below is an excerpt of a few of these cells...

WORKOUT REQUIREMENT VALVE HS669 TO BE RENEWED: RETURNED TO DESIGN INTENT BY RENEWAL OF VALVE.

RENEW THE FOLLOWING SMALL BORE VALVES: ESW617, ESW618 AND ESW648.

RENEW THE FOLLOWING INSTUMENTATION: THERMOMETERS: TX-201-MS, TX-202-MS, TX-203-MS, TX-204-MS, TX-205-MS, TX-206-MS, TX-207-MS, TX-208-MS, TX-405-MS.

PERFORM SEAT LEAKAGE TESTING ON THE FOLLOWING: 5 VALVE MANIFOLDS: FW2216, FW2217, FW2218, FW2219, FW5405, FW5406, FW5407, FW5408, FW5409, FW5410, FW5411, FW5412    GLOBE VALVES: FW5449, FW5450, FW5451, FW5452

What I'd like to do is extract the number of unique components from each of these cells, probably using a mixture of COUNTIF, SUBSTITUTE, TRIM, etc but I can't get my head around the various format combinations and volume of data.

Appreciate your thoughts!!

This is one of the best formulas I've tried:
=LEN(TRIM(A1))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1),",",""))+1
But this essentially just uses the number of commas in a string to evaluate how many words - so if the presence of commas is inconsistent, or there are normal sentences too, then it's no good.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
=SUM(N(BYCOL(SEARCH(SEQUENCE(10,,0),IF(LEN(TEXTSPLIT(A1," "))<5,"", TEXTSPLIT(A1," "))), LAMBDA(col, OR(ISNUMBER(col))))))
```

This will split each cell at every space, before replacing every word shorter than 5 characters with a blank. Each remaining word is then checked to see if it contains a number, before the number of TRUEs is summed.

The above formula returns 1, 3, 9, and 16 for the samples given - but might need some tweaking depending on your version of Excel (and also if there were any massively different component identifications - e.g. shorter than 5 characters).

Comment: Great stuff. Could you elaborate on the `OR(ISNUMBER(Col))` 'trick'. Also, `BYCOL` produces the correct TRUE/FALSE-es, but when I use `N` on that range it just returns the number 0 while `SUM(N(...))` produces the sum of ones. What's that all about?

Comment: @VBasic2008 sure. Say if the cell contained "ABC033 DEF": after being split into two, the function looks at "ABC033". First, it searches for "0", which will return the index of "0" - in this case, 4. Next, it returns two errors (1 and 2 are not present), then 5 (the index of the first "3"), then 6 more errors to complete the column. ISNUMBER(col) is then applied to the column to find whether it contains any number, the OR function prevents overcounting. I'm unable to reproduce the situation you describe with the N function, sorry. Happy to give any more detail if wanted